Unable to install Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2 in .NET Core 3.0
This is the error am getting

NU1605: Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 3.1.10 to 3.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Web -> EPPlus 6.0.8 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.1.10)
Web -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0)
NU1605: Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions from 3.1.10 to 3.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Web -> EPPlus 6.0.8 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions (>= 3.1.10)
Web -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0)
NU1605: Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing from 3.1.10 to 3.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Web -> EPPlus 6.0.8 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 3.1.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing (>= 3.1.10)
Web -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing (>= 3.0.0)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Web'.

Anyone with the solution, I will appreciate

What you posted are EPPLus warnings that have nothing to do with JSON.NET. They show you're targeting .NET Core 3.x which is long out of support. The oldest supported version right now is .NET 6 and even that reaches End Of Life in November 2024

@marc_s was able to resolved the issue by adding NoWarn in cproj
